# Satisfying typescript in dynamic component and prop selection

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics, react-context

### Aim

Creating a Context that enables easy opening and closing of diverse dialogs throughout the app. No more than one dialog can be open at a time.

TS checking should be applied to the dialog's props when they are passed alongside the dialog name into the Context, e.g. `dialogCtx.open('editing', { id: 'xyz', data: [3, 5, 6] })`

### Proposed approach

- An interface called `IDialogProps` which serves as the mapping between abstract dialog names and the components' props, and whose keys define the names.
- An object called `DIALOGS` which serves as the mapping between the names and the components.

### Issue

At `<CurrentlyOpenDialog />`, which is where the dynamic dialog is placed into the hierarchy, TS gives

```
Type '{} | { open: boolean; closeCallback: () => void; } | { id: string; data: number[]; open: boolean; closeCallback: () => void; } | { id: string; open: boolean; closeCallback: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IEditingDialogProps'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'IEditingDialogProps': id, data, open, closeCallback
```

### Question

How to satisfy TS? Alternatively, if you consider this whole approach to be deficient, what would be a better one?

### Code

For the sake of brevity, I limited the number of dialogs to three here.

**Props**

```ts
export interface ICommonDialogProps {
  open: boolean;
  closeCallback: () => void;
}

export interface ICreationDialogProps extends ICommonDialogProps {
}

export interface IEditingDialogProps extends ICommonDialogProps  {
  id: string;
  data: number[];
}

export interface IDeletionDialogProps extends ICommonDialogProps  {
  id: string;
}
```

**DialogContext.tsx**

```ts
export interface IDialogProps {
  creation: ICreationDialogProps;
  editing: IEditingDialogProps;
  deletion: IDeletionDialogProps;
}
export type Dialog = keyof IDialogProps;

const DIALOGS: {
  [d in Dialog]: React.FC<IDialogProps[d]>;
} = {
  creation: CreationDialog,
  editing: EditingDialog,
  deletion: DeletionDialog
};

export interface IDialogContext {
  open: <T extends Dialog>(name: T, props: IDialogProps[T]) => void;
  close: () => void;
}

const DialogContext = createContext<IDialogContext>({
  open: () => null,
  close: () => null,
});

const useDialogContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(DialogContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      "useDialogContext must be used within a DialogContextProvider"
    );
  }
  return context;
};

interface IDialogProviderProps {
  children: React.ReactNode; // the rest of the app
}

const DialogProvider = (props: IDialogProviderProps) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState<Dialog | undefined>(undefined);
  const [dialogProps, setDialogProps] = useState<
    IDialogProps[Dialog] | undefined
  >(undefined);

  const CurrentlyOpenDialog = name ? DIALOGS[name] : null;

  return (
    <DialogContext.Provider
      value={{
        open: (name, props) => {
          setName(name);
          setDialogProps({
            ...props,
            open: true,
            closeCallback: () => setName(undefined),
          });
        },
        close: () => setName(undefined),
      }}
    >
      {CurrentlyOpenDialog ? <CurrentlyOpenDialog {...dialogProps} /> : null}
      {props.children}
    </DialogContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { DialogProvider, useDialogContext };
```

Comment: It’s the union with undefined on the dialogProps state that is causing this particular error.  Like if you were to say `CurrentlyOpenDialog && dialogProps ? <` then you wouldn’t get an empty object `{}` included in the props type union anymore.  But you’ll have other errors because there’s no relation in TS between the name and the props and no guarantee that they match.

Comment: So the whole approach is wrong? I wonder whether it even theoretically possible to achieve my aim while satisfying TS.

Comment: It can be done, but probably requires altering some of your setup. For example, calling `open` with an object with `name` and `props` rather than separate arguments makes it easier to link the types.  Sometimes it's okay to use `as` :)  Especially in the internals of your components.  The outward-facing API is still strongly-typed so you won't pass invalid arguments.